# UI Java: Button which clears the data of a JTable

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jtable, windowbuilder

I am quite new to the creation of user interface in `Java`. I have been using the `WindowBuilder` to create an interface. I have some data from a table and I would like

- The user to check if they are double or not and hit the right button (Double, not double)
- Then, the variable double or the notdouble I would like to increase
- And in the end, to have the table cleared from the data and display the next data from the table.
- In the end, I would like to give the results of the variables (double, notdouble)

  I have written a code for action listeners of the buttons, so far in
  order to diplay some messages

```java
  // DOUBLE BUTTON
 
  JButton btnDouble = new JButton("DOUBLE");        
  btnDouble.setFont(new Font("Calibri", Font.PLAIN, 12));

  btnDouble.addActionListener(new ActionListener() { // For event handling
         
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
  {
           //Execute when button is pressed

            System.out.println("You clicked the DOUBLE button");}
  });
```

I am just writing here in order to give me some guidelines or where I should look for. Any tutorial available would be very helpful.

Comment: _I am quite new to the creation of user interface in Java. I have been using the WindowBuilder to create an interface_ If you want to learn how to create proper Java UI, try to avoid using GUI-builders. They tend to create a mess if you don't master the fundamentals behind.

Comment: This way of learning will not take you forward. As _Guillaume Polet_ suggested try to write code yourself instead of using _WindowBuilder_. For performing your task you need to learn [How to use JTable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html) from the javadoc.

Comment: I'd start with [Creating a GUI withSwing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/)

Comment: Thank you guys. I really want to learn for scratch, but I have to finish my project like yesterday and I had one day to prepare it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[How to use Button](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/button.html) and
[How to use Table](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html)

Comment: Thank you Jey for your answer. I really started from scratch finally, with the help of another question. I think it is fair to accept your answer.